# jQuery mobile stop running the script in the current page used after moving to the next page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile, loading

In my jQuery mobile application, iam having all the scripts being loaded at the index page(say index.php) and not using any (**rel="external"** or **data-ajax="false"**)for linking pages to keep the appication loaded fully with Ajax. But in my application, i want to run the script for only one page(say home.php) and after leaving that page, i want to kill the script being used.In home.php, i am using **$(document).on('pageinit', function(){ })**
for loading the script.

But i found that the script iam using in home.php is running throughout my application after leaving that page.

> How to stop the script running which is used through **page-init** function without using
>   (**rel="external"** or **data-ajax="false"**)?

Here is the code i am using in home.php,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).on('pageinit', function(){
    var auto_refresh = setInterval(
             function ()
            {
                 /*  */
                $("#color-bar").load("controller/file.txt");
                        }, 3000);
                });
</script>
```

I want to stop loading the `file.txt` after leaving home.php.

Comment: give your page in home.php an id `id="home"` and `$("#home").on('pageinit', function () { etc... });`. this will run for page #home only. Also, you can replace `pageinit` with `pagebeforeshow` or `pageshow`. and use `pagehide` to stop the interval `$('#home').on('pagehide', function () { clearInterval; });`.

Comment: I think the problem is with load() function i used, when i have some other code other than load() inside my function, it is working fine. Is there any alternative way for load() in jQuery Mobile?

Comment: there is no alternaive to `.load()` for external files. Have you tried clearing the interval?

Comment: No, it is working in the same way i mentioned but the important thing to notice is that after refreshing my home.php page and adding rel="external" to the link,it works fine, but i need without doing it.

Comment: Thanks Omar, now it is working great. I tried with `pagebeforeshow()` , `pagehide()` and `clearInterval()`.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typos in my previous comment. `rel=external` loads page *without* using AJAX. clearing interval with pagehide solved it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As, Omar suggested I want to give an id instead of  `$(document)`. Using `pagebeforeshow` or `pageshow` , `pagehide` and Clearing the interval will solve this issue. The following code works for me,

```
var auto_refresh;
$("#light-page").on('pagebeforeshow', function(){
  auto_refresh = setInterval(function () {
    // code
  }, 3000);
});

$('#light-page').on('pagehide', function () { 
  clearInterval(auto_refresh);
});
```

**Adding id in Html:**

```
<div data-role="page" id="light-page">
   </div>
```